# EACCES during hardlink creation on Linux not matching any reason in link(2) man page

Tags: linux, unix, hardlink

I have a service which assembles hardlinks to a group of files to which it has read but not write access (and traversal permissions for all parent directory trees) into a transient staging directory.

This worked perfectly, until my AWS-hosted nodes were rebooted. It appears that they're on a newer kernel now, and the link(2) calls now return EACCES.

Checking the (Linux) man page for this syscall:

> EACCES - Write  access  to the directory containing newpath is denied, or search permission is denied for one of the directories in the path prefix of oldpath or new‐path.  (See also path_resolution(7).)

For comparison, the BSD version appears to describe similar semantics, perhaps in slightly more detail:

> [EACCES]           A component of either path prefix denies search permission.
>
> [EACCES]           The requested link requires writing in a directory with a mode that denies write permission.
>
> [EACCES]           The current process cannot access the existing file.

None of these situations applies: As the user running the service, I can read the source file (including traversing to its directory), and write to the temporary staging directory (which, indeed, I created); moreover, that staging directory is on the same filesystem (though this would have caused a different error).

What gives?

Answer (score 2):

When rebooting, the new kernel booted into set `fs.protected_hardlinks=1` by default. [This was added as default behavior in late 2012.](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/800179c9b8a1e796e441674776d11cd4c05d61d7) When this sysctl is set, Linux requires write access to a file before another user is allowed to create a hardlink to it.

This is technically compatible with [the relevant POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/link.html), which states in part:

> The implementation may require that the calling process has permission to access the existing file.

---

However, [newer upstream kernels have this off by default, due to its observed ability to break third-party software](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=561ec64ae67ef25cac8d72bb9c4bfc955edfd415). Thus, it was in the present instance either reenabled by a vendor, or based on an upstream kernel from the time period between when it was introduced and later disabled.